# Not able to configure SSL on top of express server using nginx

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

With the risk of "past questions have not been well-received and I might get blocked" here is the question:

1. I'm having Domain on GoDaddy(abc.co, I've SSL certs already purchased)
2. I've EC2 instance(abc.co domain is pointing to elastic ip of this VM)
3. On the above EC2 instance my angular app(UI) is running.
4. I can access my angular app by https://abc.co
5. On same VM my node js + express app is running. (I can call APIs like http://ip:3000/api/blah)
6. I've used nginx as a reverse proxy for APIs and as a server for angular app.
7. From angular app we are calling APIs like https://ip:3000/api/blah(otherwise i'm getting mixed content error if we use http only)

Now when We call above API from angular app, we are getting below error:

on mozila: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows

reading the remote resource at https://ip:3000/api/users/login/

on chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

here is my nginx file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server{
    #listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name abc.co;

    #ssl off;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl_certs/abc.co.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl_certs/abc.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    root /var/www/html/tests;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #reverse proxy
    location /api {

            rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://ip:3000;
    }

 }
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.co;
    return 301 https://abc.co$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you access it using this url `https://abc.co/api/blah`? This way you shouldn't have Cross-Origin issue.

Comment: I'm trying your solution. But one question is when in future I'll have APIs running on different VM. I may face the same issue....what to do then?

Comment: Great!!! Your Solution worked.......You can put as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid Cross-Origin issues simply access the API using bellow url:

```
https://abc.co/api/blah
```

When you have your API running on different VM you will need to learn more about [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

There's a module for express to help you with that too.

[Cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)